# ECS awslogs Log group not being created for Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, ecs-taskdefinition

Here's part of my task definition:

```
"logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "/ecs/main-frontend-production-php",
        "awslogs-region": "us-west-1",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs",
        "awslogs-create-group": "true"
      }
    },
```

If I go view the task in the aws console it says the log driver is awslogs and to "View logs in cloudwatch" as soon as I click that I get an error: `There was an error getting log events. The specified log group does not exist.` and there are no logs.

Kind of at a loss, it seems like from this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/using_awslogs.html that I'm doing it right?

Right now my tasks are stuck in "PENDING" and I have no logs to go off of to find out why.

Comment: How does the attached IAM roles policies look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally figured this one out. The reason I had no cloud watch logs was because the image was not getting pulled from ECR. I was always under the impression that "latest" was some magical docker tag. Apparently it's not and I have to actually tag it latest for it to find it.

I think the cloudwatch logs would have been working all along, but the image couldn't get pulled, so there were no logs to speak of.

Comment: Can you please explain more on this, How did you solve !

Answer (score 6):

The possible reason that causes this error as the error seems like the container instance able to get the list of Log group.

- Make sure the container and log group are in the same region `us-west-1`.
- Make sure the container has permission to create a log group
- Just to narrow down the problem just create log-group `/ecs/main-frontend-production-php` using aws cli or aws console so you will know the actual reason as it because of region or permission.

```
aws logs create-log-group --log-group-name /ecs/main-frontend-production-php --region us-west-1
```

policy should look like

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will occur as the result of invalid permissions to write to CloudWatch logs.

You must attach permissions to the role you are using.

Follow the [Using CloudWatch Logs with container instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_cloudwatch_logs.html) documentation if you're unsure of how to do this.

Comment: Ok so I think I'm going in the right direction now, but still lost. That doc made it sound like I'm already supposed to have a role title `ecsInstanceRole` that was automatically created. I don't (using terraform maybe that's why). So I just created it, but they didn't specify what uses it? It almost sounds like it's just by convention the ECS agent will use a role with the name `ecsInstanceRole`. But I added the log policy there and the logs are still not generated. Should I add it to something? The task or the service or something? Sorry, new to AWS I'm a little lost.